# How many liters of hydrogen gas is produced per gram of aluminium?

Tags: physical-chemistry, stoichiometry

> How many liters of $\ce{H2(g)}$ at STP is produced per gram of $\ce{Al(s)}$ consumed in the following reaction?  $$\ce{2Al(s) + 6HCl(aq) -> 2AlCl3(aq) + 3H2(g)}$$
>   Express your answer to four significant figures and include the appropriate units.

My attempted solution is included below:

$$ 1.00~\mathrm{g~Al} \left( \dfrac{1~\mathrm{mol~Al}}{26.9815385} \right)
\left(\dfrac{3~\mathrm{mol~H_2}}{2~\mathrm{mol~Al}} \right)
\left( \dfrac{22.4~\mathrm{L}}{1~\mathrm{mol~H_2}}\right) = 1.245~\mathrm{L}$$

This is being marked as the wrong answer.  Where is my error?

Comment: Seems fine to me. I can only imagine that they expected that you use the standard molar volume constant of perfect gasses, which is slightly higher (and also wrong of course) $V_m=24.5$ L/mol at 298K and $p=p_0$.

Comment: The value $V_\mathrm m=22.4~\mathrm{l/mol}$ for the molar volume of an ideal gas corresponds to the old definition of standard temperature and pressure (STP), i.e. a temperature of $T=273.15~\mathrm K$ and a pressure of $p=1~\mathrm{atm}=101\,325~\mathrm{Pa}$. Since 1982, the recommended [STP](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.S06036) correspond to a pressure of $p=1~\mathrm{bar}=100\,000~\mathrm{Pa}$. At this pressure, the molar volume actually is [$V_\mathrm m=22.710\,947(13)~\mathrm{l/mol}$](http://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?mvol). However, many textbooks still use the old values.

Answer (score 6):

Your work is correct.  I have to assume that this is being graded by a computer, so trivial differences between your answer and the answer that it is expecting matter.

**Possible source of error 1:** Ideal Gas Law

Instead of using $22.4\ \mathrm{L/mol}$ they may have been expecting you to use the ideal gas law.
$$PV = nRT$$
$$101.3\ \mathrm{kPa}\times V = 0.05559\ \mathrm{mol} \times 8.314\ \mathrm{J\ mol^{-1}\ K^{-1}} \times 273.15\ \mathrm K$$
$$V = 1.246\ \mathrm L$$

**Possible source of error 2**: Units

The computer may be looking for units in liters per gram of aluminum, something like:

$$\frac{\mathrm L}{\mathrm g} \ \text{or}\ \frac{\mathrm L}{\mathrm g\ \ce{Al}}$$

I doubt that this is the case, but it's possible.

**Possible source of error 3:** Typo

Either you or the person who set up the quiz made a mistake and typed in the answer incorrectly.

Comment: I just asked my professor and he told me that "the molar volume at STP (1 bar, 0 oC) is slighly not 22.4 L" Looking in the book at can not find the value?

Comment: @user137452 The molar volume at STP ($T=0~\mathrm{^\circ C}=273.15~\mathrm K$, $p=1~\mathrm{bar}=100\,000~\mathrm{Pa}$) is [$V_\mathrm m=22.710\,947(13)~\mathrm{l/mol}$](http://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?mvol)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is 1.263 One has to use 1 mol gas = 22.414 (at 0 degrees Celsius, 1 atm) = 22.711 (at STP) in the calculation.